# How to merge csv file with xlsx file and save it into a new combined file

Tags: python, csv, xlsx

The files of both csv and xlsx contain same context, with same header and all. But would like to combine all under one file and then having another column to identify which is csv, which is xlsx. How do I go about doing so?

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}.format(extension))]
combined)csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
combined)csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index= False, encoding= 'utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by **aHelpfucoder**,

Use the below queries just before you concatenate the combined_csv & combined_xlsx dataframes to create a new column that can tell you whether a row from a **csv** file or from an **xlsx** file.

```
combined_csv['file_type'] = 'CSV'
combined_xlsx['file_type] = 'XLSX'
```

Next you can concatenate these dataframes,

```
combined = pd.concat([combined_csv, combined_xlsx])
```